# Enable Tokenizer extension in Plesk server

Tags: php, ssh, tokenize

I have a question regarding my Plesk Server. I try to install a script I bought on CodeCanyon and when I launch the installer, it reads this :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1 FatalErrorException in
>   BladeCompiler.php line 130: Call to undefined function
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\token_get_all() in BladeCompiler.php line
>   130

I did a few researches and it appears that an extension is not activated on my server : Tokenizer.

I did what the PHP manual tells me to do, via SSH, but it doesn't work.

Here is what I type :

```
php -r --enable-tokenizer
```

This results in an error :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in Command line code on line 1
```

Does anybody have an answer ? I am very new to this...

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, tokenizer extension is installed and enabled by default. You can check by executing the command:

php -m | grep tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution. Indeed, even if I have Plesk, OpenSuse 13.1, PHP 5.4.20-67.1 and everything is up to date, not only my Tokenizer was disable, but it was not installed on my PHP.

I had to install the module by adding it via SSH.

I went on www.rpmfind.net to find the right RPM module to install.

Command : `# rpm -ivh <url location>`